# Group messages by a match?

Tags: logstash, kibana

I have many messages like this:

`Error GetMilesFromLocationService(Eastvale, CA,Yorkshire, NY,1561517,19406,True.)`

The problem is that they are unique because of the city names.  In a Kibana Visualization, is it possible group these into "Error GetMilesFromLocationService" messages?  Here's an example of my metrics visual.  Ideally, they would all be in one row.

[image]

These could be easily grouped by a regex match.

Of course, I could add a new field with Logstash, but if Kibana is able to do this, I'll be happy.

Thanks!

Comment: They say you can use a server-side scripted field (as client-side scripted fields are disabled for security reasons), but I've never seen an example of it.  Using mutate->gsub to remove the stuff in the parens sounds better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) to parse the message and extract fields from it. At the very least you'll want to extract "Error GetMilesFromLocationService" into a separate field (perhaps `error_type`?) to allow aggregation. Or perhaps it would be better to extract "GetMilesFromLocationService" into a `function` field? Without knowing the structure of your log messages giving firm advice is hard.

This grok filter extracts an `error_type` field:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [
      "message",
      "^(?<error_type>Error %{WORD})"
    ]
  }
}
```